# realloc returning NULL while shrinking dynamic array

Tags: c, dynamic-arrays, realloc

Function `nodeOutputDel` is meant to delete one of the `output[]` element by replacing it with the last one and shrinking the array with `realloc` but `realloc` returns `NULL` and program exits with `errorlevel 11`.

```
struct Node
{
    unsigned int *input;
    unsigned int *output;
    unsigned int  inputCount;
    unsigned int  outputCount;
    unsigned int  id;
    bool          state;
};

void nodeOutputDel(struct Node *node, unsigned int id)
{
    unsigned int *newMem, i;
    
    for(i = 0; i < node->outputCount; i++)
    {
        if(node->output[i] == id)
        {
            node->output[i] = node->output[node->outputCount - 1];
            node->outputCount--;
            newMem = realloc(node->output, node->outputCount * sizeof(id));
            if(newMem == NULL) exit(11);
            node->output = newMem;
        }
    }
}
```

Why is that not working? I certainly did not run out of memory.

**EDIT: Thanks, I forgot about that when the last element is gone `realloc` returns `NULL`.**

Comment: Please provide complete code as a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In particular we need to see how `node->output` was set originally and whether `outputCount` is always a valid value.

Comment: Is `node->outputCount==0` after the decrement? "NULL may also be returned by a successful  call to realloc() with a size of zero."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Realloc returning NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41765761/realloc-returning-null)

Comment: As an aside, your code doesn't make much sense to me.  It seems inappropriate to resize `node->output` on *each* iteration rather than at the end, after all iterations are complete.  Additionally, when you shift elements in the array, that means that the next iteration of the loop will skip over the element that you shifted into the `i`th position.  If you're guaranteed that at most one node will match the given `id`, then you should `break` after finding the match.

Comment: @jamesdlin The output array contains only unique values. Yes it should be `return` after the match. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are deleting an item out of an array, but you need to shift everything to the right of that element in the array, one element to the left.  Use memmove to do the heavy lifting for you.

For example, if your node->output array was `[11,22,33,44]`, and you wanted to delete `22` out of it, you want to resize that array to be `[11,33,44]`.

Instead of this:

```
    if(node->output[i] == id)
    {
        node->output[i] = node->output[node->outputCount - 1];
        node->outputCount--;
        newMem = realloc(node->output, node->outputCount * sizeof(id));
        if(newMem == NULL) exit(11);
        node->output = newMem;
    }
```

This:

```
    if(node->output[i] == id)
    {
        // shift all the nodes to right of node->output[i] one slot to the left

        unsigned int shift = node->outputCount - i - 1;
        
        if (shift > 0)
        {
            memmove(node->output+i, (node->output)+(i+1), shift*sizeof(id));
        }
        node->outputCount--;

        if (node->outputCount == 0)
        {
           free(node->output);
           node->output = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            node->output = realloc(node->output, node->outputCount * sizeof(id));
        }
    }
```